# How to call in main a link list with argc and argv?

Tags: c

how to call in main this function to see if it works ? I don't even know how to call in main linked lists but with arguments it seems much more difficult .. so please someone would help me ?

```
#include "ft_list.h"

t_list  *add_link(t_list *list, void *data)
{
t_list *aux;
    aux = malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    if (aux)
    {
        aux->data = data;
        aux->next = list;
    }
    return (aux);
}

t_list  *ft_list_push_params(int ac, char **av)
{
int i;
t_list *list;

    i = 2;
    if (ac == 1)
        return (NULL);
    list = ft_create_elem(av[1]);
    while (i < ac)
    {
        list = add_link(list, av[1]);
        i++;
    }
    return (list);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
t_list *list;
    list = ft_list_push_params(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the "ft_list.h" file.

Comment: please consistently indent the code for readability/understandability by us humans.  Suggest indent 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'   Never use tabs for indenting because every wordprocessor/test editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.

Comment: 'new' is a keyword in the c++ language, and while that language is not C, the c++ compiler can be used to compile C programs.   I.E. do not use keywords for variable names

Comment: the way the code is written, if the malloc fails, that event is never passed through nor displayed to the user.   Note: usually, for non embedded applications, if malloc fails then call 'perror()' then cleanup (close files, etc) then call 'exit( EXIT_FAILURE );'

Comment: this line: 'new = ft_create_elem(av[1]));' does not compile because there is too many ')'.

Comment: to check out the code, we need the contents of the ft_list.h file posted.

Comment: this line: 'new = add_link(list, av[1]);' does not compile because the 'list' variable is not defined.

Comment: the question mentions something about using the argc and argv[] parameters, but does not list the main() function.  Are we expected to guess what your talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
        list = add_link(list, av[1]);
```

should be

```
        list = add_link(list, av[i]);
```

Optional: ft_create_elem() is not needed. add_link() can be used to push the first node on an empty list (list == NULL). I'm wondering if there should be function to display the list, and a function to delete the list (free all the allocated nodes). Since the nodes are being pushed onto the front of the list, the list will end up with the parameters in reverse order, is this what is wanted?